# Cucumber + Capybara in AJAX and update html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, cucumber, capybara

I have a dropdown which when the value is changed it does an AJAX call and renders some new content in a sub dropdown.  When doing a select of the first drop down in capybara, even though it does the select correctly, it doesn't update the second drop down.

I'm doing this to test:

```
select(province, :from => "province_id")
print page.html
```

And even though I see the province selected, I don't see the second drop down (city) being updated with the correspondent province.

What can I do?

Comment: `print page.html` won't show any changes you make via AJAX, because that data is not part of the pages source, rather the DOM is manipulated after the page is loaded.  Are you using a javascript-capable driver?

Comment: How can I know which driver I am using?

Comment: Is you Cucumber feature/scenario has `@javascript` tag? If not, then you're using Rack and thus you have no JavaScript in driver.